# slideUp-slideDown not working properly

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make some added paragraph text slideDown. I have numerous paragraphs on a page with a short teaser followed by “...read more” When the user clicks the read more link, I'd like the read more link to go away and reveal the rest of the text with a “close” link at the bottom which when clicked will slideUp to show the first bit of text, etc. I'm working in Drupal so I don't have complete control of the structure but I do have a lot.

JS:

```
$('a.views-more-link').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.comment-teaser').hide();
    $(this).next('.show-text').slideDown('slow');
});

$('.close-link a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent('.show-text').slideUp('400');
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.comment-teaser').css("display", "inline");
    $('a.views-more-link').css("display", "inline");
});
```

html:

```
<td>
    <span class="teaser">teaser...</span>
    <a href="#" class="views-more-link">more</a>
    <div class="show-text">full text...
        <br />
        <span class="close-link">
            <a href="#">close</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
```

This basically works, but I don't like the animations. It's jumpy at the beginning because I have to hide the teaser and then the full text jumps up to its position and then slides down. Closing it is even worse as the paragraph momentarily opens wider than the actual text before it slides up.  and I wonder if there's a better way (there probably is).

Comment: What about sliding up the teaser instead of hiding it?

Answer (score 0):

use `closest()` instead of multiple `parent()` or `parents()`

```
$('a.views-more-link').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).parent().find('.comment-teaser').hide(); //also here looks like it should be  teaser only
  $(this).next('.show-text').slideDown('slow');
});

$('.close-link a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.show-text').slideUp('400');
  $(this).parents('td').find('.comment-teaser').css("display", "inline");
  $('a.views-more-link').css("display", "inline");
});
```

is it `comment-teaser` or `teaser` cause i cannot find `comment-teaser` class in provided HTML code

Comment: It's comment-teaser... my bad. I'll try closest().